# how to find the tcpportnumber in win7's registry?

Tags: pptp

i read this post: [Change PPTP control connection's TCP port number](https://superuser.com/questions/381362/change-pptp-control-connections-tcp-port-number,but) i cannot find the tcpportnumber in win7's registry.so how to change pptp vpn's tcpportnumber in win 7?

Answer (score 1):

For me, the key mentioned in that answer was in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}\0003`.  To find it, I just went to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet` and then searched for `TcpPortNumber`.

Comment: hi.user1936123:is ur system win7?

Comment: fisherman: Yes, my system is Windows 7.